Bialetti Moka express moka pot discoloration after first use
I bought a new Bialetti 3 cup moka express. As per instruction, I washed with water first and brewed 3 times with only water. However right after first use, I saw that the bottom chamber has some discoloration. I did not open the mokapot after pouring out the water since it was hot. I probably let it sit for 15 mins before opening it to repeat the process - it was still hot but was able to handle it with towels. Is this normal? If not is there a way to fix it and how do I make sure this doesnt happen.


Your moka pot is probably fine, some slight discoloration or limescale deposits are normal. Could you maybe upload a picture of the discoloration?
